# Database design in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, mysql-workbench

After doing some change As Mr Vérace told me here [in this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130634/database-design-for-dentists), by changing the id names of each table into `table_name_id` and using the singular notation, I still need your opinion about this database and if it is ok to start with for a dentists application.

[image]

***Here is some information about it***

I added a table called **dentist_info** to add information about each dentist.

**Login Table** contain login information for dentists (it may be used by multiple dentists online)

The **id_logged** column is a foreign key of the id of logged in dentists, and it should be in all tables. (To let dentists see only their own patient info and details).

The **patient_id** column is a foreign key too. And it is taken from patient table and used as foreign key in med_history that represents the general medical information of the patients, patient_info that represents the general information, and the reason of visit and what tasks to do, and in the appointment table.

I have 2 questions:

1- Is there more than that information to add for a dentist database?

2- Is this database correct? Or are there errors?

Comment: Why does it take 5 characters to say 'pregnant'?  Do your patients have up to 4 billion teeth?  Seems like `TINYINT UNSIGNED` is plenty big.  Why are there 2 or more links between some pairs of tables?  Do not split DATE and TIME into separate columns; it only cause trouble later.

Comment: You have some sensitive info; be sure to run it by someone with an eye for security.  You will have hell to pay if someone hacks in.

Comment: What does "id_logged" mean?

Comment: id_logged is the id of each doctor. Assuming that this app will be used by thousand of dentists around the world @RickJames

Comment: `pregnant` it should take yes or no as values, and you right I will change the datatype

Comment: My project is in PDO, Javascript (and jquery and ajax), and MySQL as database. I think Uploading it on some secure cloud like amazon or heroku will helps alot

Comment: but what do you mean by paying too much ? For the cloud service o in case of hacking dentists info ?

Comment: "hell to pay" is an idiom that means that "great trouble", as in lawsuits, government oversight, etc.  The Cloud may give you physical security, but not much security from hackers, rogue dentists, etc.

Comment: what the best solution to make advanced security ?

Comment: Please, please, read about security, hire a security consultant, etc.  There are far more security issues than I know about, so I can't help you.

Comment: I could pose as a Dentist, get a login, then rummage through all the tables, etc.  A hacker could exploit ways to get through the client software and literally read the entire disk, or erase it.  That's just a few things I worry about in what you have designed.

Comment: Ok. I understand you. But in general, my design is good enough beside the security issue online ?

Comment: Date of birth is a key distinguishing factor.  Pregnancy and prescriptions are touchy things.