# How can I draw an entity-relationship diagram for a medical business domain?

Tags: database-design, erd

I have to develop an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) for a business domain with the following characteristics:

- A doctor consults from one clinic only, but a clinic may have many doctors working from it.
- A patient makes an appointment to see a doctor on a specific day and time.
- A patient may consult with many doctors and a doctor must consult with at least one patient.

**My current work**

I've been able to create the following diagram:

[image: ERD]

---

*Note*: I am a beginner and have just the base knowledge.

Comment: yes it is, I am a beginner

Comment: i dont want an answer but just a guidance on how can I solve the problems like this?

Comment: See my answere [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130634/database-design-for-dentists/130637#130637) - particularly the bit about Googling Open Source software!